# primary key value in mysql table always the same

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I made a mysql table with a column called 'uid' that is a primary key but not an auto increment. This is because I'm using a php rand(00000000,99999999) or whatever to fill the 'uid' with. It worked for a while until I tried to delete rows in the table. They wouldn't delete in phpmyadmin unless I checked them off and used the delete X at the bottom. The X on the same row as the record wouldn't do anything. So... when I finally had them deleted, I tried some more INSERTs from my php script, and now the uid's are the same ones that they were before even though the random number being inserted in is different. So, I figured "well i guess i don't need to make uid a primary key", so I removed that, and I just have a normal column called uid. But the problem persists. I tried to flush the mysql table. and I tried dropping the table and recreating it to no avail. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks.

Here's the table (with some columns removed)

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (  
 `uid` int(13) NOT NULL,  
 `emailAddress` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `emailAddressVerified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 `agreesToTerms` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `timestampJoined` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Did you know there is an <ENTER> key on your keyword? It is somewhere near the space key.

Comment: Why would you use php to generate a pseudo random number rather than rely on mysql's auto increment?

Comment: I need all uid's to be the same length, because they will be shown in the url: e.g., ".../profile/2379218"

Comment: @celwell, then a good solution is to have the primary key be an unsigned auto_increment int.  Have a seperate profilenumber column that you declare with your random number and add a unique index to it.  When you insert a new user, you will need to check for constraint errors, and continue to generate random numbers until you are able to successfully insert the new user in your procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the primary key as an auto increment. When a row is deleted the key will never be used again.

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused about a few things.  All phpMyAdmin does is hide the details of a the actual SQL commands.  To delete rows you use DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE...

That has nothing to do with declaring column(s) to be primary keys or not.  It will however use the primary key to do single column deletes.

You did not say why you are making a uid, but when you have a primary key, there are 2 things that happen:

1. The primary key guarantees uniqueness
2. A unique index is created

As for using rand() as the basis for generating the uid, that is not a good idea because there is always the chance that you will get a duplicate id.  It is after all, random.  php does however have a function you can use: uniqid().  Depending on parameters you get either a 13 character or 23 character return value.

I'm not sure what the explanation is for your current issue, but we would need to know the structure of your table.  One way to get this in the sql sheet is to issue this from the phpmyadmin sql form:

```
show create table yourtablename
```

Comment: I've posted the result below (so that I could format it correctly).

Comment: Hmm... I solved the issue, it was stuck on auto increment still. That code snippet below is actually after I removed the thing that was causing the original issue. I left it out because it seemed to have the same problem. Really it was a different problem that arose once I switched to uniqid(). The solution to the first issue: do "show create table tablname" then remove AUTO_INCREMENT thing from bottom (and form line with primary key if it says it there too). then drop table and run query. I think mysql was holding onto an auto increment even though I removed that attribute in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use  auto increment?

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Or worse way is "on duplicate key":

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` do not use that, it is slow and you'll run into concurrency issues.